# Error with the json-lib library for java

Tags: java, json, json-lib

I have a problem with the json-lib library for java, it turns out that if the JSON that I get only one record I have not added the [], but if you have more than one record if I add them.

This is my code that comes from a SQL query:

```
        while (oResultSet.next()) {
            JSONObject list = new JSONObject();

            list.accumulate("nombre", oResultSet.getString("nombre"));
            list.accumulate("goles", oResultSet.getInt("goles"));
            json.accumulate("list", list);

        }

        return json;
```

An example of what brings me back if you have more than one record

```
   {"list":[{"nombre":"Josele","goles":5},{"nombre":"Edu","goles":4}]}
```

And now an example with a single record

```
   {"list":{"nombre":"Eduard","goles":2}}
```

As you can see he lacks the [], and I would like to also appear as manerjar when I create the json failures.

I wish that when I have a single record also appeared to me the [ ]

Thanks for the attention

Comment: wait, so what's your question?

Comment: Sorry, if you have not understood me. I wish that when I have a single record also appeared to me the [ ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: Don't use `.accumulate()` as that's exactly what it does.

Explicitly create and add a `JSONArray` to your `json` object prior to your loop. Inside your loop, retrieve it and add to it:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("list", new JSONArray());
...

while (oResultSet.next()) {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.accumulate("nombre", oResultSet.getString("nombre"));
    obj.accumulate("goles", oResultSet.getInt("goles"));
    json.getJSONArray("list").add(obj);
}
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much, works perfectly. Although the method "put":  `json.getJSONArray("list").put(list);` not right, will have to be `json.getJSONArray("list").add(list);` for everything else perfect, many thanks :D

Comment: @user3376542 whoops, sorry, I was going off the javadocs on `json.org`, they're prob out of date. I'll edit.